# When will we get new profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I asked a generic question about this: [Why am I getting different versions of my profile page on different sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252794/why-am-i-getting-different-versions-of-my-profile-page-on-different-sites)

I just noticed that Stack Overflow and Super User (which are the oldest guys and not beta) have already been upgraded. When will SciFi.SE get the upgrade?

Comment: "When it's ready."

Comment: [Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we there yet?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18AzodTPG5U)

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today (23 November 2015), the new profiles are out on Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE:

[image: profile]

and

[image: activity]

Time to celebrate! Or mourn, depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned here:  [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

The new profile page requires an upgrade to new CSS for each site, so it's rolling out slowly.

Answer (score 2):

So far SE team haven't given the precise date. SciFi.SE is on the deck at this time: [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)